# Issue sending in method to UrlFetchApp.fetch in GAS

Tags: api, google-apps-script

Stupid question here, but I am pulling my hair out (i'm bald) as to what I could possibly be doing wrong. I am doing a UrlFetchApp.fetch in google app scripts:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: headers });
```

When using this as my headers, it works:

```
  var headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
  }
```

Now I need to pass in 'method' as 'PUT' instead of the default of 'GET' (above), and and trying like this:

```
  var headers = {
      method : 'put',
      headers : {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
      }
  }
```

When I try sending this, it is not finding the token:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.spotify.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
```

How can I format the headers so that I can pass in the Authorization with token and also pass in 'method' as 'PUT'?

I see in the URLFetchApp.Fetch documentation for Google, that this is passed into options:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

```
headers Object  a JavaScript key/value map of HTTP headers for the request
method  String  the HTTP method for the request: get, delete, patch, post, or put. The default is get.
```

Thank you so much for any help!

phi

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the method of API you want to use?

Comment: This is the GAS URLFetchApp:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

This is the SPotify URL. I can connect to the API just fine, but this particular call wants a PUT instead of a GET, and I am just not thinking how to pass that in the UrlFetchAPp.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/start-a-users-playback

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw the document of URL you provided, it is required to use the request body. But in your script, it is not used. How about this? And, although I cannot confirm `url` in your script, can I think that you are using the valid URL?

Comment: Yes, I know the call works with a simple GET method (the default so I don't have to put it in the headers being sent) I am just making a mistake in how I am sending over when adding in the "method = PUT". I am not doing that correctly and just need help adding that in to the params being sent into the URLFetchApp.fetch method.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/start-a-users-playback) And, from `I know the call works with a simple GET method`, your access token is valid.

  ```
    curl --request PUT \
      --url https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play \
      --header 'Authorization: ' \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --data '{
      "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
      "offset": {
        "position": 5
      },
      "position_ms": 0
    }'
  ```

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please modify `data` for your actual situation.

```js
var data = {
  "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
  "offset": {
    "position": 5
  },
  "position_ms": 0
};
var options = {
  method: 'put',
  headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken() },
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: JSON.stringify(data)
};
var url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
console.log(res.getContentText());
```

#### Note:

- I think that this request is the same as the curl command. But if an error occurs, please check the access token and the values in `data`, again.

#### References:

- [Start/Resume Playback](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/start-a-users-playback)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Great info!! I was putting header : header in urlfetchapp function instead of just passing the variable.

Comment: @Phi of Khem Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.